# C# .NET - MVC app with Selenium doesn't work when deployed on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selenium, localhost

I made a login automation application with C# + .NET - MVC.

My application works perfectly on my local computer and saves everything on the database.

Once I deployed my application on our local machine, the Index View receives the email and password, sends them to the database and saves them. The next step firing up a WebDriver (Firefox or Chrome worked on laptop) with Selenium. Here, nothing happens. It keeps waiting on the localhost forever and both Chrome and FF timeout after a certain period of time.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getInformation()
    {
        email = Request["getEmail"].ToString();
        password = Request["getPassword"].ToString();
        saveLogin();
        return RedirectToAction("gatherer");
    }

    public ActionResult gatherer()
    {
        facebookLogin();
        return null;
    }

    private static void facebookLogin()
    {
        chrome = new FirefoxDriver();
        chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://facebook.com");
        chrome.FindElement(By.Id("email")).SendKeys(email);
        chrome.FindElement(By.Id("pass")).SendKeys(password);
        chrome.FindElement(By.Id("loginbutton")).Click();
    }
```

This is very simple and it worked on my local computer again. But deployed on IIS on the server, it doesn't. In other words : the webdriver never opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change from

```
chrome = new FirefoxDriver();
```

To

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
Uri url = new Uri("http://REMOTE_IP:5050/wd/hub");
IWebDriver chrome = new RemoteWebDriver(url, capability);
```

Then Download Selenium Standalone server and use command prompt to initiate it using

```
java -jar C:\selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar -interactive -port 5050
```